# Span not using half of the CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have a span that will display the profile name (steam name cannot set max limit myself)

I gave the span a max width, line height, normal height, world wrap but they all don't seem to work. Could someone help me?

```css
p.raffleentry {
 width: 759px;
 height: 61px;
 font-size: 25;
 line-height: 61px;
 background-color: red;
}

span.profilename {
 font-weight: bold;
 height: 61px;
 line-height: 61px;
 max-width: 20px;
 word-wrap: break-word;
 background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<p class="raffleentry"><span class="profilename">12345678901234567890123456789012</span></p>
```

Comment: So where is your problem?

Comment: What is desired result? If you set span to display:block, or inline-block, your css will be applied, but.... http://jsfiddle.net/6ugy8h4e/ not sure that this is desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want the span to be no wider than 20px, this should work (i.e. use `display: inline-block;` and `overflow: hidden;`):

```css
p.raffleentry {
 width: 759px;
 height: 61px;
 font-size: 25;
 line-height: 61px;
 background-color: red;
}

span.profilename {
 display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-weight: bold;
 height: 61px;
 line-height: 61px;
 max-width: 20px;
 background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<p class="raffleentry"><span class="profilename">12345678901234567890123456789012</span></p>
```

Answer (score 3):

span by default displays inline, if you want to set width and height you'll need to convert that to `display: inline-block`